# Sheets script - making changes to sheets other than the initial active sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script running that reformats borders on a variable range on the active sheet.
I would like to have it cycle through other sheets in the same workbook, without those changes being visible to the user (ie - the GUI of the current screen stays as the only thing visible while the script runs).

Currently each sheet is displayed as it loops and performs the reformat.  How can I keep the initial sheet visible, and have the script run in the background?  Obviously it is the use of ".setActiveSheet" and ".getActiveSheet" causing this.

Still pretty new at all this, so any suggestions to otherwise cleanup/condense/speed up greatly appreciated.

```
function allBorders(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetname = ss.getSheetName();
  var range;
  var headrows = 3;
  var lr = ss.getLastRow() //last row with data
  var lc = ss.getLastColumn()
  var mr = ss.getMaxRows() //max possible rows
  var ns = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNumSheets()

Logger.log("Number of sheets: "+ns)

  for (var i = 0; i < ns; i++){
    Logger.log("i value: "+i)
    spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[i]);
    sheetname = spreadsheet.getSheetName();
    Logger.log("Sheetname: "+sheetname)
    switch(sheetname){
      case "Openings":
        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        headrows = 6;
        lr = ss.getLastRow() //last row with data
        lc = ss.getLastColumn()
        mr = ss.getMaxRows() //max possible rows
        break;
      case "My Trips":
        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        headrows = 6;
        lr = ss.getLastRow() //last row with data
        lc = ss.getLastColumn()
        mr = ss.getMaxRows() //max possible rows
        break;
      case "All_Trips":
        ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        headrows = 6;
        lr = ss.getLastRow() //last row with data
        lc = ss.getLastColumn()
        mr = ss.getMaxRows() //max possible rows
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
      range = ss.getRange((1+headrows),1,mr,lc) //clear all rows below header
        range.setBorder(false,false,false,false,false,false);
      range = ss.getRange((1+headrows),1,(lr-headrows),lc) //border active rows
        range.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All sheets except the first

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const allshtsexceptthefirst = ss.getSheets().filter((_,i) => i > 0).map(sh => sh.getName())
  Logger.log(allshtsexceptthefirst)
}
```

Comment: Well!  That throws me into the deep end of the pond!  But it looks like a better way to harvest the sheet names for later use, although it will take some learning on my part to know how to implement it well.  Unfortunately doesn't seem to get to the the issue of visual screen changes as the setBorder cycles through the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.forEach()`, like this:

```js
function surplusBorders() {
  const sheetsToFormatRegex = /./i;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.toast('Formatting borders...');
  let numFormattedSheets = 0;
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    if (sheet.getName().match(sheetsToFormatRegex)) {
      sheet.getRange('A1:Z').setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
      sheet.getRange(`A${sheet.getFrozenRows() + 1}:Z${sheet.getLastRow()}`).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
      numFormattedSheets += 1;
    }
  });
  ss.toast(`Done. Formatted borders in ${numFormattedSheets} sheets.`);
}
```

To only format some subset of the sheets, adjust the `sheetsToFormatRegex` [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).